# AJAX error "setRequestHeader" is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am a little confused on what I am doing wrong in my code

```
function submitArticle() { 
   var postTitle = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('postTitle').value);
   var postDes   = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('postDes').value);
   var postCont  = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('postCont').value);   
   var data = "postTitle=" + postTitle + "&postDes=" + postDes + "&postCont=" + postDes;                                     
   var getXML =  function () {
        try {

            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
          catch(e) {
            try {
              xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e) {
              try {
                  xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
              }
              catch(e) {
                alert("Your Browser is not Supported");

              }
            }                          
          }                                
      } 
       open('POST', 'http://localhost/blog/engine/engine.php', true);
       setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");               
       send(data);                                                                                                              
       getXML.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if(this.readyState === 4) {
              if(this.status ===200) {
                 alert(this.responseText);
              }
              else {
                alert("status" + this.status);
               }
          }
          else {
            alert("readyState" + this.readyState);
          }
      }
   getXML();                                                                                           
   return true;               
}
```

I am using an onclick event for this. I have checked the URL and made sure that I did not make any mistakes in entering the values of the variables.  I am getting "setRequestHeader is not defined" error  along with a new windows that shows the link "localhost/blog/app/POST"

I have looked up as much as I could and I am not sure what to do next.
Also. there must be a better way to write the code than what i did for getXML() function.

Comment: If you have so little understanding of JavaScript that you try calling object methods without any reference to the actual object, then you should maybe better us a library like jQuery that handles all that stuff quite nicely for you …

Comment: Same exact problem as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275333/which-methods-are-executed-first-in-an-ajax-call which I told you about. :)

Comment: Thanks @epascarello I have managed to get the whole thing working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setRequestHeader` is a method of the XmlHttpRequest object. [Read about it here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

You need to do `xhr.setRequestHeader(...)`.

Comment: As information, `xhr.setRequestHeader()` must be called after `xhr.open()`

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for my rather stupid question. What i didn't realize was that XMLHttpRequest has a number of methods of which open, send and setRequestHeader are a part of like what  @Chris Jones said. So I would need to use xhr."**_**" when i use those methods.

Here is my updated that works.

```
       function submitArticle() { 
           xhr = new ajaxValue();
           function ajaxValue() {
                try {
                     xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();                         
                  }
                  catch(e) {
                            try {
                              var  xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                            }
                    catch(e) {
                                try {
                                   var  xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                                }
                                catch(e) {
                                  alert("Your Browser is not Supported");

                                }
                    }                          
                  }
                  return xhr;
             }                                                                         

           var postTitle = document.getElementById('postTitle').value;
           var postDes   = document.getElementById('postDes').value;
           var postCont  = document.getElementById('postCont').value;   
           var data = "postTitle=" + postTitle + "&postDes=" + postDes + "&postCont=" + postDes;                            
           var url = '../engine/engine.php';
           xhr.open('POST', url , true);
           xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");   
           xhr.send(data);                
           xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                                       if(this.readyState === 4 ) {
                                                if (this.status ===200) {                     
                                                          alert(this.responseText);
                                                          }
                                         }                 
                                        else {
                                          alert("status " + this.status);
                                          alert("readyState " + this.readyState);
                                              }                                                
                                    }           
           return false;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
          }
```

Comment: Just accept Chris' answer, there is no point to having this here (much less accepting it).  Readers don't need your updated code dump.